# Problems using ffmpeg to make thumbnails

Tags: ffmpeg, php, streaming, mjpeg

I have a tube script that I used for years to upload video to my website which worked until I moved to another server with newer updated program features. I've had a few issues with it that I have managed to fix myself but it seems to be stuck fixing the issues with converting. I think the problem is when it gets to the making thumbnails stage (but I could be wrong).

> exec($config[ffmpeg]." -i ".$videor." -loglevel debug -an -ss 3 -an -r 2 -vframes 1 -y ".$othumb);

As you can see I have added the debug code to help work out what the issue is but so far no luck, please help and advise. Below is an output of the error.log file to help give you an idea of the problem.

`version=syslint
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 56.100 /  7. 56.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '/var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/uploads/video/33746.mp4'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-an' ... matched as option 'an' (disable audio) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-ss' ... matched as option 'ss' (set the start time offset) with argument '3'.
Reading option '-an' ... matched as option 'an' (disable audio) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '2'.
Reading option '-vframes' ... matched as option 'vframes' (set the number of video frames to output) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '/var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/images/videothumbs/33746-o-%d.jpg' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url /var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/uploads/video/33746.mp4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/uploads/video/33746.mp4.
[NULL @ 0x5601dd4c51c0] Opening '/var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/uploads/video/33746.mp4' for reading
[file @ 0x5601dd4c5d00] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5601dd4c51c0] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5601dd4c51c0] ISO: File Type Major Brand: mp42
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5601dd4c51c0] Unknown dref type 0x206c7275 size 12
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5601dd4c51c0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 102754 bytes read:132306 seeks:0 nb_streams:2
[h264 @ 0x5601dd4c9300] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x5601dd4c9300] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x5601dd4c9300] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x5601dd4c9300] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0x5601dd4c9300] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5601dd4c51c0] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5601dd4c51c0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 103165 bytes read:132306 seeks:0 frames:23
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/uploads/video/33746.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2010-04-20T14:21:17.000000Z
  Duration: 00:05:10.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2038 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und), 22, 1/44100: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-04-20T14:21:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
    Stream #0:1(und), 1, 1/30000: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, 1910 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-04-20T14:21:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url /var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/images/videothumbs/33746-o-%d.jpg.
Applying option an (disable audio) with argument 1.
Applying option ss (set the start time offset) with argument 3.
Applying option an (disable audio) with argument 1.
Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 2.
Applying option vframes (set the number of video frames to output) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[h264 @ 0x5601dd568480] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 2
[image2 @ 0x5601dd50dbc0] Opening '/var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/images/videothumbs/33746-o-1.jpg' for writing
[file @ 0x5601dd8bad00] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x5601dde72bc0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=6.7 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.50 bitrate=N/A speed=0.615x

video:19kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (/var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/uploads/video/33746.mp4):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 22 packets read (198 bytes); 
  Input stream #0:1 (video): 106 packets read (1010764 bytes); 92 frames decoded; 
  Total: 128 packets (1010962 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (/var/www/clients/client0/web9/web/images/videothumbs/33746-o-%d.jpg):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 1 frames encoded; 1 packets muxed (19964 bytes); 
  Total: 1 packets (19964 bytes) muxed
92 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x5601dd4ce100] Statistics: 1148114 bytes read, 1 seeks
video:19kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Cannot find HOME directory.`

Comment: “Cannot find HOME directory”, is that something printed by ffmpeg or something else? What is the actual issue? Is the file not written where you expect it?

Comment: no, the thumnail dosent get made, so their is nothing to add to the so called home directory.

Comment: I'm quite sure that this doesn't have anything to do with ffmpeg. The error "Cannot find HOME directory" is not from ffmpeg. Does the command not complete successfully? Can you run the command without PHP on your server and does it work then?

Comment: UPDATE: as i had to edit the error log, in-order to make it fit in the post, i must have cut out the most important line of error.log output, I need to fix this before i can worry about anything because ffmpeg wont complete with that kind of iusse, i will try to edit it back into last lind of post to help it make sense:  video:19kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown